# Nginx Directory Listing only for subpath

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-config

I am trying to make my subpath as directory listing only in Nginx, however it returns 404.

Suppose I have following config for `http://file.example.com/test`:

```
server {
    listen        80;
    server_name  file.example.com;

    location /test/ {
        root    /var/www/abc/def/;
        autoindex on;
        autoindex_exact_size off;
        autoindex_format html;
        autoindex_localtime on;
    }
}
```

I didn't specify `/` section, is it the issue caused above not working? Anything I missed?

Comment: In which directory are the files?

Comment: @RichardSmith The `http://file.example.com/test` should list files in `/var/www/abc/def/`

Comment: Nginx is looking for files in a directory at `/var/www/abc/def/test/`. Try using `alias` instead of `root`. For example: `alias  /var/www/abc/def/;`

Answer (score 2):

Change the location to `location /test`

Copy all your files to `/var/www/abc/def/test` folder, because you are using location directive along with root directive. In your case when Nginx searching static files, it will use the root path `/var/www/abc/def` and append with location path `/test`.

Or use alias as @RichardSmith suggested.